# Command 'python' not found - after I've assigned it as an alias to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, vagrant

I'm in the early stages of learning django with python. Have done none of both before.

I'm following a course where the instructor has showed how to start a new project using vagrant, and one of the files in the main directory is called `Vagrantfile`, no file extension (same for the instructor).

These are the contents of the file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
 # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
 # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

 # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
 # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
 config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
 config.vm.box_version = "~> 20200304.0.0"

 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000

 config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   systemctl disable apt-daily.service
   systemctl disable apt-daily.timer

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv zip
   touch /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
   if ! grep -q PYTHON_ALIAS_ADDED /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases; then
     echo "# PYTHON_ALIAS_ADDED" >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
     echo "alias python='python3'" >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
   fi
 SHELL
end
```

From my understanding, this line `echo "alias python='python3'" >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases` tells vagrant that when I use the `python` command, it should regard it as if I wrote `python3`.

When I write the following command though `python -m venv ~/env`, I get in response this message:

```
Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install python3
apt install python
apt install python-minimal

Ask your administrator to install one of them.
```

I call this command after I've ran the `vagrant ssh` command and I'm already inside the virtual machine, and navigate to the vagrant dir. I know it because in git bash this shows as my current location `vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/vagrant$`.

I'm not sure if it's related, or if it's a different issue, but I'll add that even if I run this command instead `python3 -m venv ~/env`, I get this response:

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/vagrant/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

If I run the install command it recommends (with `sudo`), I get this in response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

This blocks my learning, no idea how to move forward with his. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to check the contents of `/home/vagrant/.bash_aliases`? Does it include the expected alias?

Comment: If you're running this _after_ ssh-ing in, then you probably need to source your `.bashrc` file again ... unless I've misunderstood your flow here. Run: `. ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably aliasing `python3` to `python`, by default Ubuntu 18 shipped both Python 2 (python) and Python 3 (python3) and changing that  carelessly can cause instabilities, ranging from subtle bugs, to your system not booting, you can:

- use [`update-alternatives`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) to change it
- use `python3` as it is
- install the package `python-is-python3` (although I'm not sure if this is available in 18)

Anyway, by deleting the alias, everything should go back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to reproduce this on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.14-140239~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
mkdir vagrant  
cd vagrant  
vagrant init hashicorp/bionic64
vagrant up
```

At this point my Vagrantfile contains no alias. See https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/vagrant-test/blob/master/Vagrantfile.

Testing python in vagrant ssh without alias.

```
vagrant ssh
python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Testing python in vagrant ssh with alias.
At this point my Vagrantfile contains the alias from your post. See https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/vagrant-test/blob/master/Vagrantfile_with_alias.

```
vagrant reload
vagrant ssh  
python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I'm assuming the

> Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:

error is not caused by the alias in the Vagrantfile.

Try to resolve the issue by installing python3-venv.
What is the output of `python` in a terminal outside vagrant ssh?
What is the output of `python3` in a terminal outside vagrant ssh?
Which operating system are you using?
Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/958303/unable-to-create-virtual-environment-with-python-3-6.

Comment: Thank you for the help Michael! Most of what's going on here is foreign to me so can't quite point my finger on exactly what it was, but I ended up dropping the alias and going through the course again and it works now

Comment: The error message comes from the Ubuntu package `command-not-found` which is hooked into Bash to suggest fixes when users type commands which are not installed but which are known to exist in a standard package.